# When to use past tense to describe someone?

Tags: past-tense

I know that when I say "someone was a great" means he is deceased and "someone used to be great" means the one was a great once but no more. But what if I wanted to described an actor's or an athlete's performance?

Comment: This person's **performance** in this and in this event was great?

Comment: Can I say "this person was great in that movie?"

Comment: I think so. It sounds a bit informal, but I don't see anything ungrammatical about it.

Comment: But doesn't that imply this person is no longer great or he was dead? I am confused about the semantics here

Comment: You have specified "in that movie" - so the person may or may not: be alive, be great in other movies, be great outside movies etc. I don't see how it could mean that the person is no longer great in that particular movie (unless they re-shoot the scenes that you liked). Perhaps it is due to your change of opinion. But this is the proof that sometimes brevity sacrifices clarity.   I'd suggest including your sentence "this person was great in that movie" and your concerns about it in your question.

Comment: Saying *X was great* does not 'entail' (= 'necessarily imply') that 'X is dead'--that is merely your inference from the context in which *X was great* is said.

Comment: @Lucky, if I want to say this person is particularly great in the context of this person being in that movie, but not necessarily great in any other context. Does "this person was great in that movie" still make senses?

Comment: @StoneyB, really? I was taught in school only to use past tense  of be when the subject is dead

Comment: I think you misunderstood. In most (not all!) cases you must use past tense if the subject is dead; but that's not the same thing as 'you use past tense *only* if the subject is dead'.

Comment: @RexYuan Where were you yesterday afternoon? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we say:

**He *was* a great athlete.**

the only definite thing is that he is not a great athlete now. He could be older and no longer playing the sport, or he could have sustained an injury that ended his career, or he could be dead.

But if he is indeed dead, we cannot say:

**He *is* a great athlete.**

because that would mean he is a great athlete now, which he is not.

If we say:

**He was great in that movie.**

it means "his acting in that movie was great".  The actor may still be alive, but the movie was one already shown on screen. If might be shown again tomorrow, of course, but you are referring to the showing which you saw, a thing of the past. So, you would probably say "He was great in that movie" only to someone who saw the movie along with you, or if the movie was one shown a while ago and is no longer currently showing anywhere. If you are recommending the movie with this actor to a friend who has not yet seen it, you would say:

**He is great in this movie**.